# PHP randomly cuts off

Tags: php

I've made a VERY basic website which takes an array of image URLs, zips them, and returns the zip location. The problem is that the script cuts off at some point.

One of the following usually happens:

- not all the pictures are copied
- not all pictures are copied and the last picture has 0 file size
- sometimes the ajax call doesn't run the error or success callback

Is this because the server is only allowing a certain amount of time for the script to execute? It does seem to work with less pictures. What can I do?

I have the following settings:

- max_execution_time   10
- max_file_uploads 20
- max_input_nesting_level  64
- max_input_time   10

also, set_time_limit is disabled.

I tried ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); and nothing changed

edit: Probably a REALLY stupid question, but would it change anything if I executed another PHP page after a certain amount of time if the script isn't going to finish before the limit?

I'm using:

```
<?php
    include('zip2.php');
    header("content-type: text/javascript"); 


    function err($que){
        $obj->err = $que;
        echo $_GET['callback']. '(' . json_encode($obj) . ');';
        die;
        }
    if(!count($_GET['pictures'])>0){die;}
    $tmpp = tempnam('userzips','mod');
    unlink($tmpp);
    $loc = 'userzips/'.basename($tmpp);
    mkdir($loc);
    $a=$_GET['pictures'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
        copy($a[$i],$loc.'/'.basename($a[$i])) or err("didn't zip");
        }
    Zip($loc,$loc.'/pictures.zip') or err("didn't zip");
    $obj->loc = 'http://mysite.com/'.$loc.'/pictures.zip';
    $obj->allgood = true;
    echo $_GET['callback']. '(' . json_encode($obj) . ');';

?>
```

IT WILL SOMETIMES work and sometimes not for the same input. This is what really gets me.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: Since you have at least two completely unrelated problems (AJAX callbacks not being called, and server-side problems) and no absolutely no debugging information, I'd suggest you take a short break to get out of the immersion of numerous problems, then look over your code and simplify it to the point where you can successfully reproduce one problem (for example, make a new php page and simulate an input of 100 URLs). By the way, a *VERY basic* website is `echo 'Hello, world';`. Yours is pretty complicated. Also, check your apache error log for any errors that may have occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upload_max_filesize and post_max_size also can be reason

```
upload_max_filesize=100M
post_max_size=105M
max_execution_time=600
max_input_time=600
```

try to check errors while copy

```
if(!@copy('http://someserver.com/somefile.zip','./somefile.zip'))
{
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
    echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
} else {
    echo "File copied from remote!";
}
```

also I heard that there are some problems with copy  when url have spaces

Comment: Does it count as uploading if I'm copying it though?

Comment: no It doesn't =) I didn't understood question first time, so problem is in other .. do you copy images with curl ?

Comment: No, with copy(externalurl,serverurl);

Comment: Sure. Just a tad embarrassed by it :D.

Comment: Also, do I set those with ini_set? I tried, but it didn't change anything or give an error

Comment: lets see
can you add 
ini_set("display_errors","1"); ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

at the begining of the script and call script with your browser with same urls in get few times